# How to set up 'renewal reminders' 5 days after renewal, and filter by a group

Tags: civimember, groups, scheduled-reminders, 4.7.27

I want to send a note to users that renewed their membership. I want to limit that note to only a certain group of members. I thought I would use 'renewal reminders'.

In a renewal reminder, if I choose 'membership' as the entity, there is no trigger for 'renewal date', only for 'start date' and 'end date'.

But if I choose 'activity: membership renewal: completed', I can not limit the recipients (presumably the targets of the activity) to a certain group. There's just no such option.

Any suggestions on how I could do this ?

To clarify: We have several groups of members, and I want to send each renewing member a thank you note specific to his/her group

Comment: ... Where did the comments go ?

Comment: I now did this using a reminder 5 days after a payment page is received. You can limit those to groups.

Answer (score 3):

I spent some time looking through the source code and the history of this feature.  After review, I think you're best off trying to implement this via [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) instead.

- Your CiviRules trigger should be "Activity added", not membership-related.  Otherwise you run into similar limitations as the Scheduled Reminders approach.
- Your conditions can be "Activity is of type: Membership Renewal" and "Contact is in Group: X".
- You'll also need to install the [Email API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) extension so you can add an action of "Send Email".

Comment: Gee, thanks for your research! I now did this using a reminder 5 days after a payment page is received, which is 99% the same in our case... (so I wonder if I should accept the answer, as I havent tried it).